# AngularJS $http not updating variable to JSON result?

Tags: angularjs, http

I have the following in my html code.

```
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js">

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "localhost:5000"
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
            console.log($scope.myWelcome)
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
        });
    });
</script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p>Response of JSON Below:</p>
    <h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>
```

After this it just says {{myWelcome}} in the HTML it should say the response of the JSON which is already set up, and working.

No idea what the issue is.

When I run the script alone as a stand alone .JS file with just the method I get

> angular is not defined

but what thats why I included the

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js">
```

THE JSON is generated by python and looks like this

```
{"text": "Hello World!"}
```

Any ideas?

using Angular JS

Comment: @georgeawg Im not seeing any errors where would I see this im on IntelliJ

Comment: See [How to open the developer console](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/232313848-How-to-open-the-developer-console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two script elements:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js">
</script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "localhost:5000"
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
            console.log($scope.myWelcome)
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
        });
    });
</script>
```

From the Docs:

> > If a script element has a `src` attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags since it can lead to unexpected behavior. The unexpected behavior is because it is only the JavaScript in the file referenced in the `src` attribute that will be added to the HTML page.

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference - `<script>` Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: I changed the code, and it still printing {{myWelcome}} does the structure of the JSON have anything to do this...?

Comment: The code should be `$scope.myWelcome = response.data.text;` or `{{myWelcome.text}}`, but that does not explain the fact that it is not compiling the curly brackets. When there is a data mismatch, the curly brackets disappear. Something else is wrong.

Comment: so I put it in a seperate html file and ran the code and now it doesnt print out {{myWeclome}} now its completely gone just white space so I think it compiled but returned nothing?

Comment: ok so yeah it falls into the function myError section of the code.... does that mean it failed to run the get?

Comment: Check the network tab of the Developer Console for the status code of the response.

Comment: its not even going to localhost:5000 I have the server up and when I visit it it shows the status code, but when I tell the code to go visit it nothing shows up. its not even going to the localhost:5000 i would see it in the console as it prints everytime the site is accessed